# PHP: ftp_rawlist always returns false, even when in passive mode

Tags: php, file, ftp, connection

I have a problem with the PHP code shown below: I am able to connect to and login on the right FTP server. But when I try to get a list of the content of the main directory using ftp_rawlist, I always get: bool(false), even when in passive mode.

Does somebody see the problem here.

```
<?
    // Inloggegevens

    $ftp_server = "***";
    $ftp_user = "***";
    $ftp_pass = "***";

    // Verbinding maken in passive mode

    $conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 2121) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 
    ftp_pasv($conn, true);

    // Inloggen mislukt

    if (!@ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
        echo "Couldn't login on server.";
        exit;
    }

    // Inloggen gelukt

    $list = ftp_rawlist($conn, '/');
    var_dump($list);

    // Verbinding sluiten

    ftp_close($conn);  
    ?>
```

Comment: Does `ftp_nlist` work? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Comment: Tried ftp_nlist as well, unfortunately no result either.

Comment: What type of connection are you using or is expected? FTP vs FTPS vs SFTP?

If FTPS try using ftp_ssl_connect() instead.

Also, capture return of ftp_pasv() and see if it was actually successful.

$set_passive = ftp_pasv($conn, true);

Answer (score 4):

ftp_pasv() can only be called after a successful login. Otherwise will fail (i.e. return false).

Move it to after your login call.